# How to calculate the average snow amount per month for each NAME/LOCATION and then save the results in a .CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, average

For each NAME/LOCATION, calculate the average snow amount per month. Save the results in two separate .csv files (one for 2016 and the other for 2017) name the files average2016.csv and average2017.csv.

[image: Small portion of my filteredData.csv file]

I am using Python 3.8 with pandas.

I have tried this code:

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('filteredData.csv')


df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DATE']).month


df16 = df[(df.year == 2016)]
df17 = df[(df.year == 2017)]

df_2016 = df16.groupby(df.month).mean()
df_2017 = df17.groupby(df.month).mean()

df_2016.to_csv('average2016.csv', index=False)
df_2017.to_csv('average2017.csv', index=False)
```

However, it is not doing exactly what I want it to do. This is giving me the average snow amount for each month of all locations combined. However, I need the average snow amount for each NAME/LOCATION for each month. How would I be able to get the average snow amount for each NAME/Location for each month and then save the results by the years, 2016 and 2017 in separate .CSV files?

Comment: Pass a list of columns you wish to group by into the ‘groupby’ function.

Comment: `groupby` accepts a list of columns. Try `df16.groupby(['station', 'month'])` and see where you can get?

Comment: When I try to pass a list of columns into the 'groupby' function all I can get is either the same original file or just a messed up SNOW column

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average snow amount for each name/location for each month, you have to group on both of those columns:

```py
df_2016 = df16.groupby(['NAME', 'month']).mean()
```

Comment: When I try this I only see a messed up SNOW column in the new .CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['month','NAME','LOCATION']).SNOW.mean()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['year','month','NAME','LOCATION']).SNOW.mean()
```

Comment: When I try this I only see a messed up SNOW column in the new .CSV files.